# Giving Employee usergroup access to custom module - Odoo

Tags: odoo, usergroups, access-rights

I have created a module named `Purchases` containing `menu item: Purchases`and `views: Received purchases, Pending purchases` and want to give access to this module to only the `Employees\Employee`.

I have created a new user with email `emp1@gmail.com` from the `Settings` and added it to user group `Employees\Employee`. I have given the `Employees\Employee` group access rights to the `Purchases, Received purchases and Pending purchases` views.

When I log in as the employee `emp1@gmail.com` I still do not get the Menu Item `Purchases`. I only get the `Settings and Discuss` menu items.

Comment: hi can you share the code? Menu items will be visible only when menu or its child menu have an "action" defined

Comment: Under which menu, you have added menu item: Purchases?

Answer (score 0):

I got it wrong. It seems that I should have added that model to the `access rights` first and give permission to `view,read,write,delete`. Thanks.